# Phoenix Schema assigns throw Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented error in form select

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm getting the following error:

```
protocol Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented for {"Bad Product, LLC"}
```

from the following code:

ReviewController

```
def new(conn, _params) do # creating a review, the Company is a schema association
    changeset = Accounts.change_review(%Review{})
    companies = Repo.all from c in Company, select: {c.name} 
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset, companies: companies)
end
```

Template:

```
<%= select f, :company_id, @companies %>
```

From researching on SO I've tried to add `inspect`:

```
<%= select f, :company_id, inspect @companies %>
```

but that throws the following error:

```
protocol Enumerable not implemented for "[{\"Bad Product, LLC\"}]"
```

It looks like it is trying to escape it as expected, so I refactored the controller to enumerate the companies:

```
render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset, companies: Accounts.list_companies() |> Enum.map(&{&1.name}))
```

but it still throws the `Enumerable not implemented` error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks again to @sanjaykumar - they were partially correct and helped lead me in the right direction.

Including the id helped, but loading the entire schema was unnecessary. All of the following solutions work:

```
render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset, companies: Accounts.list_companies() |> Enum.map(&{&1.name, &1.id}))
```

or

```
render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset, companies: Repo.all(Company) |> Enum.map(&{&1.name, &1.id}))
```

or, what I'm going with:

```
companies = Repo.all from c in Company, select: {c.name, c.id}
```

I have limited experience with Elixir and Phoenix, but I suspect that this 3rd query is better than the other two, which are effectively the same other than `Accounts.list_companies()` resulting in another function hitting the call stack. They bring the entire Company into memory (I'm guessing), while I suspect the 3rd query only grabs the fields specified. They both also call Enum.map, so another function call.

Answer (score 2):

companies = Repo.all from c in Company, select: {c.name}

Here you are only selecting name

And you are trying to access company_id

Try

companies = Repo.all(Company)

Comment: HI! Thanks for chiming in. However, I think my last comment led you away from the real issue (I've deleted that comment). My problem is not being able to properly access the assign @companies due to either 'unsafe' html or enumeration. I think you're right though about the company id - I should probably grab that if I need it as a param :) Changing the query as you mention just includes more info about the Company in the Enumeration error.

Answer (score 1):

yes

When we call Repo.all(Company), it will load all columns of table, it also loads metadata.If we have huge amount of data there will be performance issue.

The 3rd query you have used, will return list of columns you required.This will definitely going to save bandwidth.